# Подключение phpChart в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как подключить библиотеку для генерации диаграмм http://phpchart.com/ в yii2?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй воспользоваться highcharts библиотеку

http://www.highcharts.com/demo

https://github.com/LAV45/yii2-highcharts-widget

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=yii2-highcharts-widget